# Amazon MWS - detect a returned item after order has been shipped

Tags: amazon-mws

We are trying to figure out how to detect which Orders have at least one item returned and which items are returned in the order AFTER order has been shipped. We are using the latest version of MWS Orders API (2013-09-01).

Looks like the Orders API is limited, so is there another API that we can use for this?

Comment: Do you need this information for AFN, MFN or both types of orders?